# How do I store the values of monthly temperature data in my array tempData using this add method?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I store the values of monthly temperature data in my array `tempData` using this add method?

```
public class TemperatureDataSet
{
    private double[] tempData = new double[12];

    public void add(int month, double temperature)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write

```
public void add(int month, double temperature)
{
    tempData[month]=temperature;
}
```

But be careful, `month` should be between 0 and 11 (0 corresponds to January).